How to manually refresh in Livewire
In the function "add" at some point it throws and event to the component "shopping-cart". In the "shopping-cart" component, i want to refresh the component manually when it receives the event. On the livewire site it only shows how to do it on the component view, by clicking a button and livewire handles the rest, but those function seems to not be available in the backend. Is the anyway around this or am i missing something??
//

// on the shopping-cart component
#[On('basketUpdated')]
public function basketUpdated(): void
{
    // something here
}

// Adding more products to the Basket;
public function add($value): true|LaravelNotify
{
    // Attempt to add the product to the use Basket DB
    $addProductToBasket = $this->includeInBasket($value);

    // checking for error
    if (!$addProductToBasket)
    return notify()->error('you are not connected, please connect and try again!', 'Could not update basket');

    // Event to refresh shopping cart component
    $this->dispatch('basketUpdated')->to('shopping-cart');
    return true;
}


The two components must be on the same page at the same time. Check also the name of the component that receives the event, you can use the ->to(ShoppingCart::class) format. Returning values from the  add() action is not needed.

Instead of using the On attribute, you can make a protected $listeners array and refresh when the event is triggered.
// In the shopping-cart component
protected $listeners = [
    'basketUpdated' => '$refresh'
];

public function basketUpdated(): void
{
    // something here
}


thanks @jayDey95 but it did not work, the listener is receiving the event but it is nit refreshing the component

thanks, it wasnt working at first but with some touch up it finally did. I think it was having some hidden clashes with my mount function

Anytime! Happy to help!

#[On('basketUpdated')]
public function basketUpdated(): void
{
    $this->emitSelf('refresh');
}

Update you blade with,
<div>
    <livewire:shopping-cart wire:poll="refresh" />
</div>

